# How to prevent React re-rendering using memo()?

Tags: reactjs, rerender

I have this map with different components each.

When i put export memo(function componentName()...) on every component that I have inside of this map, it's still re-render when editMode is changing state..

I also tried to useMemo/useCallback to my data state but it just keep re-renders. What exactly am i missing here?

**State**

```
const {data, setData} = useState(false)
const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false)
```

**Map Code**

```
{
  data.dataWidget.length > 0 &&
    data.dataWidget.map((item) => {
      return (
        <div
          key={item.id}
          data-grid={{
            x: item.x,
            y: item.y,
            w: item.w,
            h: item.h,
            isResizable: editMode,
            isDraggable: editMode,
            resizeHandles: ["se", "sw", "ne", "nw", "e", "w", "n", "s"],
          }}
        >
          {item.analytic_model.type != "indicator" ? (
            <div
              className={`${"border border-neutral-40 h-full flex flex-col"}`}
            >
              <div className="p-16 flex justify-between border-b border-neutral-40">
                <Header
                  setData={setData}
                  analytic_widget={item}
                  isModalVisible={() => {
                    setDataConfigModal((prev) => {
                      return {
                        ...prev,
                        isVisible: !prev.isVisible,
                        data: item,
                      };
                    });
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              {item.analytic_model.type == "canvajs_graph" && (
                <div className={`p-16 h-full canvas_js_${item.id}`}>
                  <CanvaJsGraph
                    analytic_widget={item}
                    dataDashboard={data.dataDashboard}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              {item.analytic_model.type == "chartjs_graph" && (
                <div className="p-16 h-full">
                  <ChartJsGraph
                    analytic_widget={item}
                    dataDashboard={data.dataDashboard}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              {item.analytic_model.type == "chartjs_bar" && (
                <>
                  <div className="p-16 h-full">
                    <ChartJsBar
                      analytic_widget={item}
                      dataDashboard={data.dataDashboard}
                    />
                  </div>
                </>
              )}
              {item.analytic_model.type == "leaflet_position" && (
                <div className="p-16 h-full">
                  <LeafletPosition
                    analytic_widget={item}
                    dataDashboard={data.dataDashboard}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              {item.analytic_model.type == "leaflet_polyline" && (
                <div className="p-16 h-full">
                  <LeafletPolyline
                    analytic_widget={item}
                    dataDashboard={data.dataDashboard}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              {item.analytic_model.type == "datatable" && (
                <div className="p-16 h-full overflow-y-auto">
                  <DatatableDashboard
                    analytic_widget={item}
                    dataDashboard={data.dataDashboard}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <Indicator
              analytic_widget={item}
              dataDashboard={data.dataDashboard}
              dashboardHeader={
                <Header
                  setData={setData}
                  analytic_widget={item}
                  isModalVisible={() => {
                    const element = document.getElementById(
                      `dashboard-${item.id}`,
                    );
                    element.style.display = "block";
                  }}
                />
              }
            />
          )}
        </div>
      );
    });
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with component re-rendering when its state has changed. If you want to get around this, consider moving state out (make them dummy components) and passing whatever is required as props (which you can memoize with `useMemo()`, too).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @YevhenHorbunkov! Reason why I want to prevent the re-render is because in those components, it's fetching some datas, which is heavy for something like changing edit state only. Is there any insight from you for doing something like this? Or is it bad to fetch under loop components like this? I will try the useMemo() too, thanks.

Comment: Data fetching should be done inside a `useEffect`. You should not rely on a component rendering a specific number of times.

Comment: I use your option and I just realize that it's working! make it async fetch to fetch data for each component make the components has a loading state for each and that's what i wanted. Somehow i forget the basic. Thanks! @RossAllen